# How to move a NodeJS project from Windows to MacOS?

Tags: node.js, git, github, mern

I'm working on a NodeJS project on my Windows laptop. I'm about to buy a Mac and wanted to work on that project from the Mac. I have a git repo for the project, which is also set up remotely on github. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to move that project to the Mac. Could someone highlight the steps and specific git commands I would have to run in order shift that project to my Mac. Also, what would happen to the dependencies I've installed?

Answer (score 0):

You want to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then

```
brew install node
```

after that clone your repo and `npm install`

Comment: Where should I run this brew command?

Comment: in your terminal